# WCF Service with UriTemplate - "Length cannot be less than zero"

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0, sitecore

I have a pretty simple WCF service set up with a method similar to:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetById/{id}")]
ResponseSingle<BinderViewModel> GetById(string id);
```

When I try and hit it with a GUID like...

**http://localhost/services/myservicename.svc/GetById/5c3f04d7-f96e-4acd-847b-6da5937e**

It returns a 500 and an exception stating:

> Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length

If I remove the UriTemplate and instead hit it as:

**http://localhost/services/myservicename.svc/GetById?id=5c3f04d7-f96e-4acd-847b-6da5937e**

It works fine.

I've done a bit of reading and it looks like the request will fall over when it grows > a certain length.

Wondering if anyone else has been bitten by this previously and if so had any luck resolving it?

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: Are you sure that in endpoints configurations set proper path to your service?

Comment: Can you post your configuration section for the above service? I did try the same and it works as expected without any problem. Also 500 error is an internal server error which might be due to other reasons as well. Just enable tracing to see the exact reason on why its failing

Comment: I would suggest you check out WCF WebAPI (ASP.NET Web API)  http://wcf.codeplex.com/ It removes a lot of the headache when trying to setup simple services.

Comment: @paramosh yep the endpoints are OK, see my edit. If it was a problem with endpoint, first request wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetById/{id}")]
```

Should be:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetById?id={id}"]
```

---

Adding more information (as I was confused for a second), `/Action/{variable}` is for the path of the service.  I.e., /GetBy/ID or /GetBy/Name

Whereas, the method is expecting a value to complete processing of the service, so that will have to be a query in the syntax `?CaseSenstiveMethodParameterName={queryParameter}`

[MSDN URL Template Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx)